# odometry configuration

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi ,
i want to make a robot, i install ros on raspberry and i want to get odometry with ros_arduino_bridge. so i have pololu shield  VNH5019 and 2motor metal gear encoder.
my problem is electrical, how to connect is how to pololu shield with motors?
can you help me please if you have cable schematics please?

i just ask for connexion between motor and shield motor. i have this: My motor has 6 pins:

```
Red motor power (connects to one motor terminal) 
Black motor power (connects to the other motor terminal) 
Green encoder GND 
Blue encoder Vcc (3.5 – 20 V) 
Yellow encoder A output 
White encoder B output
```

and my shield:

```
M1INA Motor 1 direction input A 
M1INB Motor 1 direction input B 
M1EN/DIAG Motor 1 enable input/fault output 
M2INA Motor 2 direction input A 
M2INB Motor 2 direction input B 
M1PWM Motor 1 speed input 
M2PWM Motor 2 speed input 
M2EN/DIAG Motor 2 enable input/fault output 
M1CS Motor 1 current sense output
M2CS Motor 2 current sense output
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236305/odometry-configuration/) by [Emilien](https://answers.ros.org/users/26246/emilien/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As far as you showed here your board is not able to read odometry data.
A link to the original board datasheet would help

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2016-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2016-06-08**:
As it is not the job of this board, the encoder connection should be made to the Arduino. I would ask this question on a hardware/basic robot page, not here.